# How to space items using probability?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm writing a software, where I need an event to occur on average 10 times per 24 hours.

I want to implement that by checking a random number against preset probability every second.

I've tried $10^{1/(3600\cdot 24)}-1$ as that probability, but that is incorrect. I also can calculate that probability using simulation, but that seems lame (as there may be delays in execution, and I want to be  able to seamlessly adjust the interval and always get the correct result).

Can anybody help me with the formula and the rationale behind it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $24\cdot3600=86400$ checks in $24$ hours; if you want the expected number of occurrences to be $10$ the probability needs to be $10/86400=1/8640$. By [linearity of expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) the expected number of occurrences is $86400$ times the expected number of occurrences in one check, which is just $1\cdot p+0\cdot(1-p)=p$, the probability itself.

Comment: ) oh my. and there I was trying to find a complicated way to solve this! thanks a lot!